# How to change location and refresh page in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function :

```
$scope.insert = function(){
    var data = {
        'username' : $scope.username,
        'password' : $scope.password,
        'nama_lengkap' : $scope.nama_lengkap
    }

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: './sys/mac.php',
        data : data
    }).then(function(response){
        return response.data;
    });
}
```

and the function work perfectly, but i want my page change to datalist and refresh datalist after insert() true. my function insert() run in the route "localhost/learn/#!/administrator" so i want it change to route "localhost/learn/#!/" after insert() true. i used location.href='#!/' but it not work for refresh datalist automaticaly, just change location.

Comment: You'll need to post the structure you want to update as well so we can actually see what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update an object from a service call, you can do the following. I have added an onError function too, to help with debugging.

Tip: Research adding service calls into a `Service` that AngularJS framework provides. It helps for writing maintainable and structured code.

```
$scope.objectToUpdate;
$scope.insert = function(){
    var data = {
        'username' : $scope.username,
        'password' : $scope.password,
        'nama_lengkap' : $scope.nama_lengkap
    }

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: './sys/mac.php',
        data : data
    }).then(function(response){
        $scope.objectToUpdate = response.data.d;
    }, function(e){
        alert(e); //catch error
    });
   }
```

**Optional Service**

Below is an example of how to make use of Angular Services to make server calls

```
app.service('dataService', function ($http) {
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    this.getData = function (url, data) {
        // $http() returns a $promise that we can add handlers with .then() in controller
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: './sys/' + url + '.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
        });
    };
});
```

Then call this service from your controller, or any controller that injects `DataService`

```
var data = {
            'username' : $scope.username,
            'password' : $scope.password,
            'nama_lengkap' : $scope.nama_lengkap
        }
 dataService.getData('mac', data).then(function (e) {
    $scope.objectToUpdate = e.data.d;
 }, function (error) {
    alert(error);
 });
```

Comment: No problem, mark the answer as correct if this helps.